# Not a valid month error

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have a problem with python development.

I try to insert records to my database table, but I have this error when I try to insert them using `cx_Oracle` for python: `not a valid month.`

And when I try to run this same query in `sqldeveloper`, there is no problem.

This my code:

```
cursor.execute("insert into mytable(tableid,tablename,timecreate)values('45125','test',to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yy')))")
```

I don't know what is the difference?

Have you any idea?

Comment: It is invalid.  Why are you just not using systimestamp function instead of sysdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want just the mm/dd/yy (remove hours,mins,sec) from a sysdate and convert to a timestamp, try this instead of your to_timestamp call:

```
CAST (trunc(SYSDATE) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

No need to convert to char and back.

Comment: Even this is too complicated  -  why not use your own suggestion, and simply write   trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP) and avoid using any cast at all?